# How do I retrieve a td value in PHP based on the row of the submit button pressed?

Tags: php, html

I would like to being able to see a td value based on the row that a 'submit' button is in. [image]

Here is my html code

```
<?php foreach($books as $booklist) : ?>
        <tr>

            <form action = "." method = "post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addtocart" >
            <td><img height="50" width="50" src=<?php echo "/../../product_manager/uploads/".$booklist['productimage']; ?>></td>
                    <td><?php echo $booklist['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $booklist['version']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $booklist['releaseDate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $booklist['price']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $booklist['quantity']; ?></td>

            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value = 'Add to cart'/><td>
            </form>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here is my controller

```
 if($action == 'addtocart'){

echo $booklist['name'];
}
```

My problem is that it is echoing the last row only. If I echo version, price etc, it only echos the product named test. How can I get it to echo based on the submit button row? Also I'd like to keep it strictly php or html only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the submit button an array based name such as name="submit[0]". That way you can use a counter variable in your loop to assign the value to the submit button and determine which button was pressed.

The above is my recommendation which you should use with a single form element. According to the HTML standards, a form should not be contained in a tr element, only in a td element. Therefore your form element should be contain your table and not the other way around.

Instead of a for loop, you can also try reading the value as:

```
$arr = array_keys($_POST['submit']);
echo $arr[0];
```

Comment: I updated my answer as I did not realiize at first you were using multiple form elements inside your tr elements. A form element is not allowed to be inside a tr element.

Comment: "a form should not be contained in a tr element" Even though that is correct, I doubt any browsers would fail to render the page correctly. The problem looks to me like OP hasn't actually outputted the product ID anywhere, so it is adding the last product to the card. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: *"A form element is not allowed to be inside a tr element."* - May not be a good idea, but I don't completely agree with that statement.

Comment: how would assigning an array to the submit button, give me that submit buttons row?

Comment: @triswill227 Because the key of the first element of the array `$_POST['submit']` will be the row number. Personally I prefer a hidden input element named something like "product_id", but do whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Indeed, so the first row would have a button named submit[0], the second row would have a button named submit[1], the third row would have a button named submit[2], etc.

Comment: Ah okay so that makes sense but how do i implement this? Im thinking use some form of a loop to give submit a number then returning the name and parsing this to just the number?

Comment: Yes, you already have a loop, so just use the existing loop with a variable which increments by one each time through the loop.

Comment: thank you i created a for loop and then used the isset command as i looped pass each submit button checking if its array spot was pressed. No the most efficient way by any means, but it gets the job done for now

Comment: @triswill227 I have added further info that will probably be more efficient than a for loop. Be sure to test it of course. Also, something else to think about: what happens if the user presses Enter to submit the form instead of clicking a button?